# Ruby: ActiveAdmin Gems: How can we retrieve all the registered resources?

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

Is it possible to retrieve all the registered resources for Active Admin interface?

I have registered a lot of resources in active admin and I want to have a list of registered resources so that it can put into my dropdown box.

Possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guarantee there must be a cleaner way, but you can access your Models that have been added as to AA by accessing the resources collection in the namespace you have defined.  For example, if you have AA defined in the :admin namespace

```
 > ActiveAdmin.application.namespace(:admin).resources.select {|r| r.respond_to? :resource_class_name}.map(&:resource_class_name)
```

will produce and array of class names..

```
=> ["::Activity", "::ActivityType", "::AdminUser"]
```

that gives you a list of items you can massage into a dropdown.

Comment: Nice oneliner. We use activeadmin with several namespaces though, so this could be an expansion:   `ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces.collect{|ns,v|[ns,v.resources. select {|r| r.respond_to? :resource_class_name}.map(&:resource_class_name) ]}` Generating links to the index-pages of all these resources (nested or not) is a whole other challenge. Maybe activeadmin-resource exposes a method to get a link for a certain resource?

Answer (score 0):

```
# I came up with this to generate a hash of
# :namespace => array of arrays containing 2 elements
# [title, link]
#
# With this <strikethrough>it should be trivial to</strikethrough> you can
# create a clickable select.

Hash[*
  ActiveAdmin.
  application.
  namespaces.
  collect{ |ns,v| [  
    ns, 
    v.resources.
        keys.
        select { |k|
            r = ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[ns].resources.find_by_key(k)
            r.respond_to?(:resource_class_name) && !r.belongs_to?
        }.

        collect{|k|
          [
            k, 
            begin
              Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(
                ( 
                  "#{ns}_" + 
                  k.underscore.pluralize.gsub('/','_') + 
                  "_index_path"
                ).to_sym
              ) 
            rescue
              Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(
                ( 
                  "#{ns}_" + 
                  k.underscore.pluralize.gsub('/','_') + 
                  "_path"
                ).to_sym
              )
            end
          ]
        } 
  ]}.
  flatten(1)
]
```